# Adding fmod via gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, fmod

With Android-Studio being the new standard, we are looking into switching our project to gradle.
We are using FMod in our project and I tried adding FMod to our project as a Module. I added the following `build.gradle` for FMod:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

artifacts.add("default", file('fmodex.jar'))

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "fmodex"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run gradle, it fails with:

```
2014-12-09 21:48:40,050 [2584434]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '/home/android' 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/home/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:186)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:361)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':fmodex'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':fmodex'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:86)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidTargetHash.isPlatform(AndroidTargetHash.java:179)
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidTargetHash.getVersionFromHash(AndroidTargetHash.java:127)
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidTargetHash$getVersionFromHash.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidTargetHash$getVersionFromHash.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.configureLanguageLevel(BasePlugin.groovy:2384)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.this$2$configureLanguageLevel(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$this$2$configureLanguageLevel$14.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$this$2$configureLanguageLevel$14.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createCompileTask(BasePlugin.groovy:1429)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantFactory.createTasks(ApplicationVariantFactory.java:187)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:274)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:216)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createAndroidTasks.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:463)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure9.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:408)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    ... 39 more
2014-12-09 21:48:40,052 [2584436]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - A problem occurred configuring project ':fmodex'. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A problem occurred configuring project ':fmodex'.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:368)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Does anyone have experience with adding FMod to gradle?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `artifacts.add`, rather than the more conventional choices for Gradle for Android (e.g., `compile fileTree()` in `dependencies`)?

Comment: Can I add ndk binaries with `compile fileTree()`?

Comment: I am not aware that `artifacts.add()` has any support for the NDK. `compile fileTree()` is for a JAR. If the JNI libraries are from a third party, put them in `jniLibs/` in your `main` sourceset. If the JNI libraries are being built using Gradle for Android's `ndk` closure, those libraries should be added for you. And if you are using **`ndk-build`**, there's a recipe floating around for effectively monkey-patching the Gradle for Android build process to include those libraries.

Comment: I was under the impression, that prebuilt native binaries could be added via `ndk` closure, too. And I really would like to have the dependencies abstracted in an own module if possible.

Comment: "that prebuilt native binaries could be added via ndk closure, too" -- not that I am aware of. "I really would like to have the dependencies abstracted in an own module if possible" -- and that's fine. However, `fmodex.jar` presumably is not an NDK binary. Try using `dependencies` and `compile fileTree()` for **adding the JAR**, in addition to what you have for the `ndk` closure. If that does not help, try switching to `jniLibs/` for pre-built NDK binaries instead of the `ndk` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to actually run, when doing it correctly. Seems like the error was only missing properties. The following works:

```
apply plugin: "android-library"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "fmodex"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('fmodex.jar')
}
```

Comment: Hi @abergmeier . Do you have an Android Studio Module for FMod ? I'm about to create one, but if you can share it, maybe on github, I'll gladly use it ;)

Comment: No sorry, had to work on other projects shortly after.